# Como aceder a um campo especifico de um objeto JSON usando JAVA

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

Estou usando Java para obter informação do Twitter e o REST client do [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/).

Como teste fiz um PUT de info em JSON e depois usei o `performRequest` para obter um elemento especifico.

```
//create a json to PUT at the ES
    Map<String, String> params2 = Collections.emptyMap();
    String jsonString = "{" +
                "\"user\":\"Luisinho\"," +
                "\"postDate\":\"1988\"," +
                "\"message\":\"esta a começar a andar\"" +
            "}";
    HttpEntity entity = new NStringEntity(jsonString, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    Response response4 = restClient.performRequest("PUT", "/posts/doc/2", params, entity);


    //Search the document using Query Params

    Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    paramMap.put("q", "user:Luisinho");
    paramMap.put("pretty", "true");

    Response response5 = restClient.performRequest("GET", "/posts/_search",
                                                               paramMap);

    System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response5.getEntity()));
    System.out.println("Host -" + response5.getHost() );
```

E obtive o elemento pretendido desta forma:

```
   {
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.2876821,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "posts",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "user" : "Luisinho",
          "postDate" : "1988",
          "message" : "esta a começar a andar"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

Host -http://localhost:9200
```

**1-**
É possivel obter esta informação já como um objeto JSON?

**2-**
Como não sei como fazer a primeira, converti aquela informação para um objeto JSON, mas como faço para obter o value da key "message" que é o que me interessa?

Tentei algo como:

```
String nova=EntityUtils.toString(response5.getEntity());
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(nova);
String message = jsonObj.getJSONObject("hits").getString("message");
        System.out.println("JSON  "+message);
```

Mas não consigo obter o valor pretendido.

Answer (score 1):

Para ficar mais simples a obtenção do valor "message". Crie um pojo com todos os campos retornados do json. Feito isso, utilize a biblioteca GSON para converter o seu json para o pojo criado. Dessa forma, você irá conseguir obter o valor sem problemas!

Algo semelhante a isso:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonInString = "   {
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.2876821,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "posts",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "user" : "Luisinho",
          "postDate" : "1988",
          "message" : "esta a começar a andar"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}";
PojoCriado pojoCriado= gson.fromJson(jsonInString, PojoCriado.class);
pojoCriado.getHits.getMessage();
```

Comment: POJO é algo novo para mim. Pelo que estive a ver funciona como uma espécie de Model de um objecto? Tenho de criar esse posso com todas os 18/19 campos retornados? E ao fazer gson.fromJson(jsonInString, PojoCriado.class) o que ele faz? faz os sets de todos os campos? Desculpe a ignorância e obrigado

Comment: Perfeito amigo! É justamente isso. Ao fazer o gson.fromJson(jsonInString, PojoCriado.class) ele irá setar os valores do do seu pojo de acordo com o arquivo passado como parâmetro .